# Differentiability of a function of two variables

Tags: derivatives

Is the function 
\begin{equation}
f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{2xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} & (x, y) \ne (0, 0) \\
  0 & (x, y) = (0, 0)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
differentiable at the origin?

Answer (score 2):

The partial derivatives are equal to $0$. However,

$$\lim_{h,k \to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0+k) - f(0,0) - 0h - 0k}{\|(h,k)\|_2} $$

Is not zero (it does not exist). So no, it's not differentiable.

Comment: $f_x$ is $2y^3/(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}$. Along a line $y = kx$, its value is $2k^3/(1 + k^2)^{3/2}$. Therefore, in the limit x tends to zero, $f_x$ does not tend to a unique value. Would it be correct to assume $f_x(0, 0) = 0$?

Comment: @AmeyJoshi I'm not assuming that, it's actually equal to $0$. What has the limit of $f_x$ as $x,y \to 0$ to do with the **value** of $f_x$ at $(0,0)$?

Comment: $f_x(a,b)$ is by definition: $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(a + t,b) - f(a,b)}{t}$

Comment: Thanks, I see your point now.